# For a given balance and an annual interest rate, calculate the minimum fixed monthly payment to pay off debt in a year

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparative-review, calculator, finance

Interest is compounded monthly. Payment doesn't  vary from month to month.

Version 1

```
balance = 999999
annualInterestRate = 0.18
mRate = annualInterestRate/12
high = (((mRate+1)**12)*balance)/12
low = balance/12
guessed = False

def balanceLeft(balance,mRate,minPayment):
    monthsLeft = 12
    while monthsLeft > 0:
        unpaidBalance =  balance - minPayment
        interest = mRate * unpaidBalance
        balance = unpaidBalance
        balance += interest
        monthsLeft -= 1
    return balance

while guessed == False:
    minPayment = (high + low) / 2
    if round(balanceLeft(balance,mRate,minPayment),2) < 0:
        high = minPayment
    elif round(balanceLeft(balance,mRate,minPayment),2)> 0:
        low = minPayment
    else:
        if abs(round(balanceLeft(balance,mRate,minPayment),2) - 0) < 0.01:
            guessed = True

print('Lowest Payment: ',end='')
print(round(minPayment,2))
```

Version 2

```
annualInterestRate = 0.18
rate = annualInterestRate / 12
monthsLeftr = 12
xCoefficent = 1 + rate
ConstantTerm = 1 + rate
while monthsLeftr > 1:
    xCoefficent = (xCoefficent + 1) * ConstantTerm
    monthsLeftr -= 1


balance = 999999
monthsLeft = 12
while monthsLeft > 0:
    balance = balance * ConstantTerm
    monthsLeft -= 1
minPayment = balance / xCoefficent


print('Lowest Payment: ', end="")
```

I would like a comparative and overall review, please!

Comment: Given any 3 of payment amount, term, interest rate, and initial principal, the fourth one can be calculated algebraically, except for interest rate, which requires a search. C code for all these at http://www.dragonreef.net/ammo.c.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## General comments

- use a consistent style: space after a comma, or not; spaces around operators, or not; even two spaces sometimes. Python has an official style guide called [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which is worth a read, you’ll understand why the syntax highlight here is colouring `ConstantTerm` in light blue.
- use functions to parametrize values. As it stand it is impossible to reuse any of that code to perform computations with other rates, initial lending, or even various number of years.
- use the [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) clause to wrap your top-level code.
- use a `for` loop to perform the same computation a given number of time. *e.g.*:

  ```
  for _ in range(monthsLeft):
      balance = balance * ConstantTerm
  ```
- use constants for magic numbers: `MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR = 12`

A first and quick rewrite could be:

```
MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR = 12


def balance_left(balance, monthly_rate, monthly_payment):
    for _ in range(MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR):
        unpaid_balance =  balance - monthly_payment
        interest = monthly_rate * unpaid_balance
        balance = unpaid_balance
        balance += interest
    return balance


def minimal_monthly_payment(balance, annual_interests):
    monthly_rate = annual_interest / MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR
    lower_bound = balance / MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR
    higher_bound = (monthly_rate + 1)**MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR * lower_bound
    guessed = False

    while not guessed:
        monthly_payment = (higher_bound + lower_bound) / 2
        yearly_balance = balance_left(balance, monthly_rate, monthly_payment)
        rounded_balance = round(yearly_balance, 2)
        if rounded_balance < 0:
            higher_bound = monthly_payment
        elif rounded_balance > 0:
            lower_bound = monthly_payment
        else:
            if abs(rounded_balance - 0) < 0.01:
                guessed = True
    return monthly_payment


if __name__ == '__main__':
    minimal_cost = minimal_monthly_payment(999999, 0.18)
    print('Lowest Payment:', round(minimal_cost, 2))
```

```
MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR = 12


def annual_rate_coefficient(monthly_interests_rate):
    coefficient = monthly_interests_rate
    for _ in range(MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR - 1):
        coefficient = (coefficient + 1) * monthly_interests_rate


def minimal_monthly_payment(balance, annual_interests):
    monthly_interests_rate = 1 + annual_interests / MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR
    for _ in range(MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR):
        balance = balance * monthly_interests_rate
    return = balance / annual_rate_coefficient(monthly_interests_rate)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    minimal_cost = minimal_monthly_payment(999999, 0.18)
    print('Lowest Payment:', round(minimal_cost, 2))
```

## Version 1

You can rearange the maths in `balance_left` to make it more efficient:

```
balance = unpaid_balance
balance += interest
```

is equivalent to

```
balance = unpaid_balance + interest
```

is equivalent to

```
balance = unpaid_balance + monthly_rate * unpaid_balance
```

is equivalent to

```
balance = unpaid_balance * (monthly_rate + 1)
```

is equivalent to

```
balance = (balance - monthly_payment) * (monthly_rate + 1)
```

so:

```
def balance_left(balance, monthly_rate, monthly_payment):
    monthly_interests_rate = 1 + monthly_rate
    for _ in range(MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR):
        balance = (balance - monthly_payment) * monthly_interests_rate
    return balance
```

You can also simplify `minimal_monthly_payment`:

- you can use an infinite loop and `return` from it instead of using a flag;
- you don't need the test `if abs(…) < 0.01` because you know from the previous `if` and `elif` that `rounded_balance` is neither > 0 nor < 0. So `rounded_balance` is 0 and you have found your minimal monthly payment.

```
def minimal_monthly_payment(balance, annual_interests):
    monthly_rate = annual_interest / MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR
    lower_bound = balance / MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR
    higher_bound = (monthly_rate + 1)**MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR * lower_bound

    while True:
        monthly_payment = (higher_bound + lower_bound) / 2
        yearly_balance = balance_left(balance, monthly_rate, monthly_payment)
        rounded_balance = round(yearly_balance, 2)
        if rounded_balance < 0:
            higher_bound = monthly_payment
        elif rounded_balance > 0:
            lower_bound = monthly_payment
        else:
            return monthly_payment
```

## Version 2

I find this version more interesting because the algorithm is more efficient. The computation is straightforward and doesn't compute intermediate results that are only a mean to tighten the bounds.

It may benefit from using comments to explain why this approach is computing the right result.

Anyway, we can still improve it: it uses 2 `for` loops that are almost the same. Can't we make it both be `for _ in range(MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR):` and merge them? I will necessitate to integrate `coefficient = monthly_interests_rate` into the loop. Luckyly, `(0 + 1) * monthly_interests_rate` is `monthly_interests_rate`:

```
def annual_rate_coefficient(monthly_interests_rate):
    coefficient = 0
    for _ in range(MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR):
        coefficient = (coefficient + 1) * monthly_interests_rate
```

so now we can merge both loops:

```
MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR = 12


def minimal_monthly_payment(balance, annual_interests):
    monthly_interests_rate = 1 + annual_interests / MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR
    coefficient = 0
    for _ in range(MONTHS_IN_A_YEAR):
        coefficient = (coefficient + 1) * monthly_interests_rate
        balance = balance * monthly_interests_rate
    return = balance / coefficient


if __name__ == '__main__':
    minimal_cost = minimal_monthly_payment(999999, 0.18)
    print('Lowest Payment:', round(minimal_cost, 2))
```

## Going further

Defining `minimal_monthly_payment` as a function will allow you to import it in an interactive shell and test it with various amounts and rates. But you could also integrate a command-line parser so you could call your script like:

```
python <module_name>.py 999999 0.18
```

You can try to manually take the content from `sys.argv` and convert it, or let a specialyzed module do the job. For instance [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Minimal monthly payment calculator')
    parser.add_argument('balance', type=int, help='initial lending')
    parser.add_argument('rate', type=float, help='annual interests rate')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    minimal_cost = minimal_monthly_payment(args.balance, args.rate)
    print('Lowest Payment:', round(minimal_cost, 2))
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a problem that can be solved exactly with a little math, so there should be no need to program a search.

Suppose that we borrow initial capital \$c\$ at a monthly interest rate \$r\$, paying it off in \$n\$ months with a monthly payment \$p\$. (Here \$r\$ is expressed as a multiplier, for example if the monthly percentage rate is \$2\%\$ then \$r = 1.02\$.)

In this scenario the outstanding balance is $$ \eqalign{
cr - p &= cr^1 - p(1) & \quad\text{after 1 month;} \\
(cr - p)r - p &= cr^2 - p(1 + r) & \quad\text{after 2 months;} \\
((cr - p)r - p)r - p &= cr^3 - p(1 + r + r^2) & \quad\text{after 3 months;}}$$ and so after \$n\$ months the balance is $$
cr^n - p(1 + r + r^2 + \dots + r^{n - 1}) = cr^n - p{r^n - 1\over r-1}. $$ If this pays off the debt exactly then $$ cr^n - p{r^n - 1\over r-1} = 0 $$ and so $$ p = {cr^n(r-1) \over r^n - 1}.$$

Since payments typically have to be made in integer numbers of pennies (or whatever the minimum unit of account is) then you'll want to round \$p\$ up to the nearest penny.

Answer (score 4):

**Wrong results**

Your implementation says the loan cut (each month) should be 90325, when the correct answer is 91679.90. (See [here](http://www.calculator.net/loan-calculator.html?cloanamount=999999&cloanterm=0&cloantermmonth=12&cinterestrate=18&ccompound=monthly&cpayback=month&x=77&y=8).)

**Use mathematics**

Next, let us do some actuarial mathematics. Suppose the initial principal is \$A\$ (in you program 999999 units), and let \$p\$ be the monthly payment. Next, let \$F_k\$ be the balance after \$k\$ months, let \$i\$ be the monthly interest rate, and let \$m\$ be the number of months (in your case \$m = 12\$). Also, let \$r = 1 + i\$. Since

$$
F_k = rF_{k - 1} - p, \quad k = 1, 2, \dots, m
$$

we have the following identities:

\begin{aligned}
F_0 &= A, \\
F_1 &= r F_0 - p, \\
F_2 &= r F_1 - p = r^2 F_0 - r p - p, \\
& \dots \\
F_m &= r^m F_0 - \sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} r^j p \\
    &= r^m A - \sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} r^j p.
\end{aligned}

Since we must have paid the loan completely after \$m\$ months, we must have \$F_m = 0\$, which yields the following identity:

$$
\sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} r^j p = r^m A,
$$

which leads to

$$
p = \frac{r^m A}{\sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} r^j}
$$

Next, let us find the closed form for the sum \$S = \sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} r^j\$:
\begin{aligned}
S - r S &= \sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} r^j - r \sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} r^j \\
              &= \sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} r^j - \sum_{j = 1}^m r^j \\
              &= 1 - r^m.
\end{aligned}

Since \$S - r S = S(1 - r) = 1 - r^m\$, we deduce that

\begin{aligned}
S &= \frac{1 - r^m}{1 - r}.
\end{aligned}

Finally, we have
\begin{aligned}
p &= \frac{r^m A}{\Big( \frac{1 - r^m}{1 - r} \Big)} \\
  &= \frac{(1 + i)^m A}{\Big( \frac{1 - (1 + i)^m}{1 - (1 + i)} \Big)} \\
  &= \frac{-i (1 + i)^m A}{1 - (1 + i)^m}.
\end{aligned}

Compiled into Python, this is

```
def compute_loan_cut(principal, month_interest_rate, total_months):
    divisor = 1 - pow(1 + month_interest_rate, total_months)
    return -month_interest_rate * pow(1 + month_interest_rate, total_months)\
                                * principal / divisor

print("Loan cut:", compute_loan_cut(balance, mRate, 12))
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The math would look a lot nicer if you picked a name for the value \$1 + i\$.

Comment: @GarethRees Thank you for your input. I will rewrite the math soon.

Comment: @GarethRees Done.